# Strange performance with hybrid MPI/OpenMP on EC2

Tags: c++, multithreading, amazon-ec2, mpi

I'm having a problem running a hybrid MPI/OpenMP on an EC2 instance.  Namely, I can't make sense of the performance I'm seeing.

My application can essentially break the compute job into n parts.  For the purpose of the question, let's say 4 parts.  At the moment, I expect to see pretty much the same performance if I do the 4 parts all MPI or all with threads (openMP).

Here's the performance I get for various MPI/OpenMP configurations and command lines:

Do all 4 parts with OpenMP.  This is confusing.  If I run

```
mpiexec -np 1 myapp
```

It takes about 20 seconds.  If I do

```
./myapp
```

It takes about 10 seconds (???).  If I run each part in a separate process, like

```
mpiexec -np 4 myapp
```

It takes about 5 seconds.

I am fairly certain I am setting up the number of threads correctly, such that when I run in four proccesses with MPI, there is only 1 thread per process, but running in one process, there are 4 threads.

Here are a few other details:

- I'm using C++ and boost::mpi.
- I don't make any MPI calls in threaded code.
- Every time I do mpiexec, I see something like this:

  ```
  A high-performance Open MPI point-to-point messaging module
  was unable to find any relevant network interfaces:

  Another transport will be used instead, although this may result in
  lower performance.
  ```
- I see the expected performance pattern on my own PC, although my own PC is much slower.
- I'm using a c4.2xlarge instance.

Comment: Does adding `--bind-to none` to the list of `mpiexec` options change anything?

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not yet sure if this is the only problem, but it was for sure part of the problem.  This fixed the discrepancy between mpiexec -np 1 myapp and ./myapp.  Unfortunately they both still run at half the perf. of -np 4, with one thread per process, or -np 2 with 2 threads on each process.

That feels like I might be having some real memory bw or false sharing issues, but I'm not sure.  Anyway, you've scooted me along a bit, guess I have to read up on that stuff a bit.

Comment: It is unlikely a memory bandwidth issue as it would affect the case with 4 MPI processes too. Inefficient OpenMP parallelisation, including false sharing, is a plausible case.

Comment: With 4 MPI processes, at least each process will (probably) allocate memory on the socket where the computation takes place.  With 4 threads, unless I'm careful, I think everything will be allocated on one socket, but computation may take place in a core nearer to the other socket.  That was my thinking anyway.  I have to dig more.  Thanks again.

Comment: The "first touch" NUMA policy does not distinguish between threads and processes. As long as the threads are distributed the same way among the CPUs as the processes, the memory will be allocated the same. Except if you happen to initialise the working memory in the sequential part of the OpenMP program, then all memory ends up on the same node.